# Stylish popup in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The alert box/confirm box which we get in javascript are simple popup box. I need to modify the box style. Means to make the text bold, and to make these pop up stylish. How can I achieve that??

Comment: You can't modify the message box that results from the alert() and confirm() calls. You'll need to create your own custom alert box. You can use something like the jQuery UI dialog box: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: That comment should be an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with traditional browse popups. You have to use a javascript/modal popup.

Here's an example:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 4):

You can't modify the message box that results from the alert() and confirm() calls. You'll need to create your own custom alert box. You can use something like the jQuery UI dialog box: http://jqueryui.com/dialog